# Gaia Framework based flash web site updates

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, frameworks

I have a flash web site based on gaia framework which I never used before. 
I need to update my homepage by adding a button for which I created a .png graphic to be imported and linked to an external url.

After poking around I was able to understand I had to add the following code to the page xml:

```
<setting>
        <src>images/slideshow/my_button.png</src>
        <link>http://www.myexternalURL.com/,_blank</link>
        <y_offset>10</y_offset>
</setting>
```

However, I am aware that this by itself will not display my button. I need to edit other files and add the code that will display the button. 
Is there anyone that can help me figure out this? 
I would like to learn how to do it so if I need to make other changes in the future I can...
thank you

Comment: You can start by taking a look on their documentation here : https://github.com/stevensacks/Gaia-Framework/wiki

Comment: I am looking at it because I want to understand how gaia framework works. I actually got a grasp of how the web site is structured, but I have no knowledge of AS3...I would like to learn it all, but in the meantime get help to add that button to my page...